# Inheritance in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I want to have one class that has common information; `CommonData` class will be used in all tables:

```
 public class CommonData
 {
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = "";
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; } = "";
    public Nullable<DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public Nullable<DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
 }
```

Person class:

```
   public class Person 
   {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

I know I could do this if I put all of the data in a common class

```
public class CommonClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = "";
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; } = "";
    public Nullable<DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public Nullable<DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

If I inherit from the common class

```
public class Person : CommonClass
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I have looking at the table it creates and I feel that their must be a better way to do this. When the table is created it puts all of the `CommonData` in the first fields of the table then it put all of the specific table data. It makes it a mess.

I have tried this to make this but this didn't work I like to have this data in a `CommonData` object connected to the `Person` class. This would be the ideal scenario but I don't know how to achieve this.

```
 public class Person 
 {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
   
    public CommonData CommonData {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Why care about the order of columns at all? If you created your tables, then added a new property to CommonClass, the migration would just add the new column to the end of the table.

Comment: Most DBA's like columns uniform.  For me I also like it that way.

Comment: My point was that you will need to constantly tweak migration scripts by hand if you wish to keep database column order the same as your object definition order. Since this is not a "feature" that EF Core cares about.